# Class Functions in Other Classes - Binary Tree, Dictionary, Contact List (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I've got 3 classes: a binary search tree, a dictionary, and a contacts list. The dictionary uses the binary tree, and now I'd like the contacts list to use the dictionary. The issue is that unlike the tree and dictionary classes, the dictionary and contacts classes use a different number of parameters. This means that where I can use wiktionary.find() in the dictionary class, as marked in the code, I cannot do  the same with wontact.find() in the contact list class, also marked. Can anyone help me figure out how to use the dictionary functions in the contact list class?

Dictionary (this works and uses functions from the tree)

```
#include "bst.h"



template <class K, class V> class Dictionary
{
public:

    BinarySearchTree<K,V> wiktionary;  //this is what I can't do in contact list

    Dictionary()
    {
    }
    ~Dictionary()
    {
    }

    V & find (K key)
    {
        wiktionary.find(key);     //uses find function in tree
        return wiktionary.find(key);
    }

V & operator[] (K key)
{
    try
    {
    find(key);
    }catch(key_not_found_exception)
    {
        insert(key, 0);
    }

    return find (key);
}


private:

};
```

And the contact list:

```
#include "dictionary.h"

class ContactList
{
public:
    ContactList()
    {
    }
    ~ContactList()
    {
    }

    Dictionary<K,V> wontact; //This is what I'm trying to achieve, 
    //but K and V are invalid according to compiler



    /*
     * Looks for an entry in contacts that matches name and 
     * returns the phone number of that entry

     * Returns:
     *  if found string representing contacts phone number 
     *  else returns an empty string
     */

    string lookup (string name)
    {
        wontact.find(name);  //this is what I'd like to do


        //Work in progress

        else
        return "";
    }


private:

};
```

Comment: With templates, your `K` and `V` in `Dictionary` are *placeholders* for when you use the class. Assuming "key" and "value" what types  should they be...? `std::string` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, these will both be strings

Comment: Then replace both `K` and `V` in `Dictionary<K,V> wontact;` with `std::string` (just like you would do for `std::vector<std::string>`).

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I'll accept the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using a C++ templated class, you need to supply the actual types you want to use (for example: `std::vector<std::string>`).

In this case, for Key and Value of `std::string`, you would declare your class member as:

```
Dictionary<std::string, std::string> wontact;
```